# How to set PID limit for containers in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-machine

I have used docker-bench-security on one of the kube-node to check best practices, I found one warning that PID limit is not set on containers.
So Please provide a solution that how do I set PID limit for container in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

[Since Kubernetes 1.14](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/15/process-id-limiting-for-stability-improvements-in-kubernetes-1.14/), the kubelet supports limiting the number of PIDs a container can start.

The configuration parameter is called [`PodPidsLimit`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/apis/config/types.go#L245) so depending on your Kubernetes distribution, you'll have to set that in your kubelet configuration.

Comment: also check here: [Stack Overflow - How to Set PID Limit in Kubernetes Pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272911/how-to-set-pid-limit-in-kubernetes-pod)

Comment: As of now, GKE does not support manually changing the `PodPidsLimit` but they are in constant development. If this function is blocking your development, you should reach Google support for advice!